# Can't seem to get correct value from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In ScriptA, I have a random value (call it rndmInt) being called in Awake().
In ScriptB, I'm trying to correctly get the value of rndmInt in ScriptB's Start().

I (think) it's set up correctly, as when I use Debug.Log(), it doesn't pop up with errors saying something like "Can't access ScriptA.rndmInt" or anything.

In ScriptB, I have a Debug.Log() basically saying Debug.Log(ScriptA.rndmInt). I of course have made rndmInt public in ScriptA, but when I try to link ScriptA onto ScriptB, it won't let me do so directly. I instead have to put ScriptA onto a GameObject, and then drag and drog that GameObject onto ScriptB in the inspecter, and reference the GameObject. I'm thinking that has something to do with it but I really don't know.

In ScriptA's rndmInt, it would correctly and truly log a random integer. When I try to log ScriptB's attempt of getting rndmInt from ScriptA, it always logs "0", instead of the correct value. ScriptA isn't always 0.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access other scripts by referencing them.

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int rndmInt;
    ...
}

public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ScriptA scriptA;
    void Start()
    {
         Debug.Log(scriptA.rndmInt);
    }

    ...
}
```

Based on your question I can only assume that you're currently using a new instance of ScriptA in your Debug.Log that returns you the default value of an integral type.

Comment: I've taken a better look at my code, and apparently ScriptB is getting the default value of rndmInt in ScriptA. I want it to get rndmInt AFTER ScriptA has randomized it in its Awake() function. How would I do that?

Comment: Actually, whatever value I put into the inspector seems to override any other value I put in ScriptA's default value of rndmInt. ScriptA can still log the correct random value of rndmInt, but ScriptB uses whatever value is in the inspector.